# Кнопка "Подробнее" и "Скрыть" вместе со стрелкой

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Имею такой вот код, но он не работает, при клике на кнопку у меня стрелка не загружается "вверх" для слова "Скрыть". Выше есть блоки, там такой же код и все работает. проверил 100 раз. возможно есть другой способ? Что бы при клике на кнопку "Подробнее" рядом была стелочка вниз, а при клике на "Скрыть" стрелочка вверх.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
$(".link__click1").click(function() {
   $(".link__click1").text(function(i, text){
    return text === "Скрыть" ? "Подробнее" : "Скрыть";
   });
   if($(".arrow__image10").attr("src") == "img/arrow__white.png"){
    $(".arrow__image10").attr("src", "img/arrow__white2.png"); 
   } else {
    $(".arrow__image10").attr("src", "img/arrow__white.png"); 
   }
  });
```

Comment: Консоль выдает ошибку? Если да то какую?

Comment: не выдает, дело в том что эти кнопки находятся внутри slick-slide может в нем проблема....не знаю..

Comment: У вас `.arrow__image10` находится в `.link__click1` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 var flag=0;
        $(".link__click1").click(function() {
            $(".link__click1").text(function(i, text){
                return text === "Скрыть" ? "Подробнее" : "Скрыть";
            });
            if(flag==0){
                $(".arrow__image10").attr("src", "img/arrow__white2.png");
                flag=1;
            } else {
                $(".arrow__image10").attr("src", "img/arrow__white.png");
                flag=0;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Возможно как то так?

Comment: все спасибо, разобрался